# Security concerns with including creds in POST/PUT request

Tags: rest, security, url, authentication

I've got a situation where I need to pass in unencrypted user credentials in a POST/PUT request like so, in order for an REST endpoint to work: `http://bob:bobspassword@something.com/path/to/rest/endpoint`

It's giving me the heebeejeebies. Any security concerns I should be worried about? Strikes me as just a bad idea, but that's the way the API was designed...

Comment: Yes, in the absence of a VPN, it's insecure. But as to whether you should be concerned....that depends on the value of the information being transferred. Adding TLS to this should be trivial, hence another question is whether you can get the same service elsewhere.

Comment: Use HTTPS, that encrypted the data in transit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is insecure. The simple solution is to use HTTPS, that securely  encrypts the data as well as the query string in transit.